# socket cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++, udp, winsock2

Hi I have done Java and C# and recently did a module in C/C++ on the Linux environment. I have decided to make a simple UDP server in C++ in windows which I am new too but not a complete newbie when it comes to coding. I have looked as some examples and it all seems to work apart from this one line:

```
SOCKET socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

when I compile this in Netbeans it comes up with this error message:

```
classUDPServer.cpp: In constructor 'UDPServer::UDPServer()':
classUDPServer.cpp:35: error: '((UDPServer*)this)->UDPServer::socket' cannot be used as a function
    make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/classUDPServer.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
    make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I have both winsock2.h and iostream included.

Can anyone help me with this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't name your variable the same way as a function.

```
SOCKET my_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

Moreover, as @chris points out, you could use the scope resolution operator(::) so that the function `socket` is looked up in the global namespace:

```
SOCKET socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

Comment: yer thank you I have just seen that myself! I feel a little silly know! lol Thanks for your quick response though! :)

Comment: I'd like to point out that this is simply a scope issue. Using `SOCKET socket = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);` will work just fine and allow for using the desired variable name.

Comment: I didn't actually ever know that until just now when I had one of those "Wait a minute. What if I...?" moments.